# Trouble using RcppEnsmallen

Tags: r

I successfully used Ensmallen to optimize an objective function.

I compiled my program in Ubuntu linux using
the following command:

g++ himmelblauadam.cpp -o himmelblauadam -O3 -larmadillo

This is the c++ code modified for RcppEnsmallen:
himmelblau_adam.cpp

```
#include <RcppEnsmallen.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEnsmallen)]]


class Himmelblau{
public:
  double Evaluate(const arma::mat& x) {
    return ( x[0]*x[0] + x[1] - 11.0 )*( x[0]*x[0] + x[1] - 11.0 ) + (x[0] + x[1]*x[1] - 7.0)*(x[0] + x[1]*x[1] - 7.0);
  }
  void Gradient(const arma::mat& x, arma::mat& gradient){
    gradient[0] = 4*x[0]*(-11.0 + x[0]*x[0] + x[1]) + 2.0*(-7.0 + x[0] + x[1]*x[1]);
    gradient[1] = 2*(-11.0 + x[0]*x[0] + x[1]) + 4*x[1]*(-7.0 + x[0] + x[1]*x[1]);
    
  }
    
  void Shuffle(){}
  
  size_t NumFunctions(){
    return 1;
  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat himmelblau_adam(const arma::vec& x){

  Himmelblau hb;

  arma::mat beta = arma::mat(1,2);

  beta[0] = x[0];
  beta[1] = x[1];
    

  ens::Adam opt(0.001, 16, 0.9, 0.999, 1e-8, 10000, 1e-5, true);
  
  opt.Optimize(hb,beta);

  
  arma::mat beta2 = arma::mat(1,3);

  beta2[0] = beta[0];
  beta2[1] = beta[1];
  beta2[2] = hb.Evaluate(beta);
  
  return beta2;
}
```

This code generates a cascade of errors. The last message:

Error in Rcpp::sourceCpp("himmelblau_adam.cpp") :
Error 1 occurred building shared library.

But if I change the optimizer and use

```
 ens::L_BFGS opt;
 opt.MaxIterations() = 100;
```

In this case RcppEnsmallen works perfectly well. No errors of any kind.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  This is not a reproducible question: we cannot help you with what you posted.  There is no code, so it is hard to impossible to help you.  Look at what other questions do, and/or look at [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: The Problem is not with my c++ code but with the compilation made by rcppensmallen. My code is too long to be put here. But it runs without problem in c++.

Comment: The general tip is to make it smaller to prove the point that it works.  I start many Rcpp tutorials by showing `Rcpp::evalCpp("2 + 2")`.  If that works, chances are more complicated things will too.  If it fails, more complicated things would fail too. 
As the saying goes: may want to try to _walk_ before you try to _run_ or _sprint_.  Clearly _something_ is not right in your setup, and we still cannot help irrespective of how you repeat that you think all is well. _We cannot replicate._  So we cannot help.

Comment: I modified my original post and included the code of a toy application with the same problems as my program.  I am using R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15) -- "Shortstop Beagle"   Thanks for your time.

Comment: I can replicate, and it fails to compile for me with from within R, and outside on the command-line. However, the `Adam` example from https://ensmallen.org/docs.html#optimizer-documentation compiles fine (just prefixing `ens::` and `ens::test` as needed) so methinks your `Hummelblau` has an issue preventing `Adam` use.

Comment: And if you read the docs for Ensmallen you will see that you must supply a _Differentiable seperable function_ for `Adam` with a richer interface than you provided: you need different signatures for `Evaluate()` and and `Gradient()` so the compiler was, as usual, correct to complain.  No `Adam` for your `Himmelblau`.

Comment: Thank you for your Time. The strange thing is that when I compile in c++ the Himmelblau program with different optimizers it works very well. My original Kalman filter  worked well with most optimizers offered by Ensmallen.  But I want to have access to all this algorithms in R.

Comment: Yes you keep repeating that statement. The most likely explanation is that you used different versions of Ensmallen. See maybe `ensmallen_bits/ens_version.hp` and compare between the two installations.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved the issue already.  The problem was, that in the exported function the argument was const. I changed it to //[[Rcpp::export]]    arma::mat kf_optim(arma::mat &theta){ }. Everything is fine now. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, interesting.  So maybe one of the compiler flags automatically added by R (say, `-pedantic`) may have triggered that.  Anyway, glad  you are up and running now!  Being able to test C++ snippets outside of R and use them with R is a nice feature so I am glad you could make use of that.